# Simplest way to write this AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html

I need to send an ajax request to a webserver "http://examples.com/ajax" the response will be the html of a `<div>` and it will be inserted to an existing `<div id="holder">`. What's the simplest, smallest way to write this in javascript? without using jQuery?

It only needs to support the latest version of chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  //Is request finished? Does the requested page exist?
  if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {   
    //Your HTML arrives here
    alert(req.responseText);  
  }
}

req.open("GET","http://examples.com/ajax.php",true)  //true indicates ASYNCHRONOUS
req.send(null);
```

This solution uses `get`, so you've got to add variables using `?` and `&` to your URL (e.g. `http://examples.com/ajax.php?foo=bar&blah=blee`.

If you want to do it using `post`, run a few with `get` and then [this article is useful](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php).

Comment: thanks. how do I insert req.responseText into <div id="holder">?

Comment: @rana: `document.getElementById('holder').innerHTML = req.responseText`

Comment: also for error handling I can just add an else to that if statement right?

Comment: PHP errors will come across as `responseText` so you can see them directly. HTTP errors (e.g. 404 "can't find page") will be seen in `req.status`.  A status of 200 indicates everything went OK with your HTTP request.

Comment: is this solution cross browser compatible? if not @steve can you modify it