# Having problem in fetching data from database using PHP MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have tried a very simple example of PHP MySQL Ajax following the example -

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_in_action.htm

I created two files putting these in a same folder and uploaded it to the server.I have also checked the connection with DB from the php file. But I don't understand why the html file does not bring any data from the the database. What's wrong with that. The example i followed can be found here.

http://aiworker2.usask.ca/age/ajax.html
http://aiworker2.usask.ca/age/ajax-example.php

I'm very new in AJAX and really don't understand what's going on.
Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents: First of all, try a [simpler Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112521/simplest-way-to-write-this-ajax-call/4112526#4112526) to get yourself used to the mechanics of the thing.

All you have to do on the PHP side is `echo` out some data.  For example, you could have your ajax open "test.php", then have "test.php" look like this:

```
<?php echo "working"; ?>
```

Then, just alert `yourRequest.responseText` (the response text property) and it should say "working".

Once you've got this moving smoothly, you can modify the PHP file to make a MySQL request.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... it went well..I'll now try to have a look on the rest of the work..

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it really worked. Now I'm able to do all sort of query operations using ajax.. Thanks a lot!