# scan files in a directory using ajax/javascript

Tags: ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

Im a beginner of javascript and ajax. and i would like to use
ajax to populate my  tag with  which are the
content of a particular directory.

is there such opendir() fxn in ajax just like in php?
Where do i start from here?

Comment: Do you want to scan directories on the *visitors* computer, or your server? The first won't be possible due to the nature of Javascript which does not provide any Filesystem functions. The second would require a serverside script.

Comment: on my server.. what do you mean by a server side script? i am running the page on the server itself sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use ajax to access PHP, you can start with [a simple ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112521/simplest-way-to-write-this-ajax-call/4112526#4112526) and return the `scandir` results.

A quick guide for beginners can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150332/having-problem-in-fetching-data-from-database-using-php-mysql-php/4150372#4150372), which should start you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to list files in either a server or client directory.  You can make a server wrapper script for this, but it may be better to approach it at a higher level (e.g. return a list of resources, while not exposing the implementation of a resource).