# file_Get_contents in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, phpjs

i want to get data from other sites using javascript executed from my website.

Answer (score 5):

The [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/) website has some nice conversions of PHP functions into Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

In general, unless they expose the data with [JSON-P](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/), you can't thanks to the security considerations imposed by the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Recent browsers support a [permissions system](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) where a remote site can allow JavaScript running on a remote site to make a request. Flash provides a similar system, so can act as an intermediary. Both of these require the cooperation of the remote site.

The usual work around is to use a proxy service, either running on your own system (so JS makes the request to the same server, which fetches the data from the remote site) or a third-party service like [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is limited by the same-domain security policy. The only way to get data from other sites is to use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) or build a proxy on your own host that lets you `curl` content from other sites.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's other PHP ways besides `curl` also, but I'm too lazy to look for them - `file_get_contents` of course springs to mind.

Comment: Sure, but that's just shorthand for `curl`. Not part of the question though, the user asked whether he/she could fetch content from other domains.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
$.post( 'http://some.website.com/file.js', function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```

You may not fetch anything but JavaScript or JSON.

Or try this answer: [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

It has to be done server side - send an [ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112521/simplest-way-to-write-this-ajax-call/4112526#4112526), run the PHP you want, and check the `responseText` property to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on what you mean by "data". Try using AJAX if its just for simple requests.

Comment: Everyone posts so quickly here; I feel redundant.